# pdf4net failing for no visible reason

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation

We have a legacy setup that creates pdf's on the fly based on client info.   I can follow everything through where the process gathers the info and everything runs normally, until it gets to the doc.Form.FlattenFormFields then it goes in to limbo.   I've captured the base64binary string and it tried to use that to convert to a pdf with no luck also.

Anyone have any ideas or tips on pdf4net.  I know this is a vague question but a lot of the system is a black box so we aren't even sure where to start.

Comment: Did this work before?  When did it break?

Comment: Yes it worked previously and still works for other docs called from different methods but the process to create those is different. Sometime last week is when it stopped but it was working after our last update to the webservice.  The confused part is this process calls some stuff from Strata frame and an old legacy web service that are both kind of black boxes so we can't see what's happening at that point.   Prior to the calls to pdf4net everything looks good.  no weird characters or anything.  At some point the data is converted to a memory stream but that again is one of the black boxes.

Comment: so we can't see what's happening there.  The only thing I can think at this point is create my own method for the memory stream conversion so we can eliminate that as an issue.

Comment: Can you save the stream out to a PDF file and then write a small app that tries to do the doc.Form.FlattenFormFields call?  It could be a structural problem with the PDF.

Comment: Turns out the stream was where the problem was located. Somewhere it is getting corrupted, possibly with the weird way the previous developer used the session object and strata frames.  We've bypassed all the black boxes and are just streaming the file in .net and it's working in our tests now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK figured out that the problem was corruption in the memory stream of the pdf.   The process is using Strata frames (a black box) and passing in a doc ID and session parameters which are stored in a cookie.  We had to change the cookie a week or so back because some clients session cookie was getting too big (he was storing a butt load of data in the cookie).   We bypassed the Strata frames call that created the memory stream and are creating our own in .net and it is working in the test environment now.